# Rich text Editor (ribbon based) in a webpart in SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, 2013, ribbon, rte

My goal is to create a rich text editor for a textarea in my custom webpart in SharePoint 2013. The data is saved outside the SharePoint, so I can't really use a sharepoint list for that.

I really like the way rich text editors work in SharePoint 2013 when you edit list items with enhanced rich text fields:

[image: rich text editor with ribbon while editing a list item]

When I use a built-in RTE control in my markup [SharePoint:InputFormTextBox](http://sharepointerz.blogspot.se/2012/07/sharepoint-rich-text-input-control.html):

```
<SharePoint:InputFormTextBox ID="rftDefaultValue" 
    RichText="true" 
    RichTextMode="FullHtml" runat="server" 
    TextMode="MultiLine" Rows="5">
</SharePoint:InputFormTextBox>
```

It gives just an inline RTE in IE or nothing in Chrome:

[image: Inline Rich Text Editor in IE and Chrome]

The question is:

**Could it be possible to use the cross browser ribbon based Rich Text Editor in custom webpart textareas?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might also want to try this little [jQuery plugin](http://shareden.blogspot.ru/2013/06/jquery-plugin-for-sharepoint-2010-that.html)

It allows you to enable Ribbon WYSIWYG editor while you are in edit mode.

It works simply like this: 
`$("#myDiv").SPEditable();`

And the result might look like this: [image]

And this is a real life example where this can be really useful: 
[image]

Update: Now this plugin supports SP 2013:
[image]

Answer (score 6):

Yes it is possible, check this tutorial out that is demonstrating how to create a Visual WebPart as a Text editor and it's also connected to Ribbon as claimed by author, however it's for SharePoint 2010 but I am pretty sure it will work as it is or with some changes for SharePoint 2013 as well.

[Develop a custom editable Visual Web Part (WebPart)](http://zootfroot.blogspot.co.uk/2010/09/develop-custom-editable-visual-web-part.html)

**Helpful Links**

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15668474/webpart-with-custom-editorpart-does-not-save-data

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3614989/how-can-i-extend-the-ootb-content-editor-web-part-in-sharepoint-2010

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3771519/develop-a-custom-editable-visual-web-part-webpart-for-sharepoint-2010/3786142#

**Edit**

Blog Post is too lomg to add here but description is here,

> I wanted to create a web part for Sharepoint 2010 that would let an
>   editor add a block of free-form html to a page, but wrapped up in a
>   nicely formatted HTML container of my choosing. I also wanted the web
>   part to include some custom properties to allow the user to select
>   some permutations for the HTML container (colour, position etc.). The
>   key thing was that when the editor is amending the content, I wanted
>   to be able to use the standard ribbon controls instead of having to
>   hook in a 3rd party rich text control like Telerik RadEditor.
>
> So, I assumed I could just take the build-in Content Editor Web Part
>   (CEWP) and extend it. No dice - cos it's sealed!
>
> So I ended up whipping out Reflector and digging into the CEWP code,
>   ripping the guts out of it to hack a new webpart. The following Web
>   Part does what I set out to do, and maybe it will be a good base for
>   you too.

Comment: Thank you @Muhammad, I will absolutely try this solution. Could you describe the solution a little bit in your answer so that one knows what the answer is [even if the link gets broken in the future](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-answer)?

Answer (score 6):

My complete solution for SharePoint 2013 - style ribbon-based rich-text editor. I made this some time ago, so I certainly borrowed some code from google.

### ASPX / ASCX:

```
<div id="editor">
    <div id="RTEDiv" tabindex="0"></div>
    <asp:HiddenField ID="RTEDivHidden" runat="server" />
    <div class="commands">
        <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" Text="Submit" runat="server" CssClass="editorbtn" />
        <input type="button" value="Cancel" id="btnCancel" class="editorbtn" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Simple div container, future rich text div `id="RTEDiv"`, hidden field to post data and two simple buttons.

### JS:

```
(function ($) {
    // add SP13 rich text params to div
    $.fn.SPEditable = function () {
        return this.each(function () {
            $(this).addClass("ms-rte-layoutszone-inner-editable ms-rtestate-write").attr("role", "textbox").attr("aria-haspopup", "true").attr("contentEditable", "true").attr("aria-autocomplete", "both").attr("aria-autocomplete", "both").attr("aria-multiline", "true");
        });
    };
    // remove SP13 rich text params from div
    $.fn.SPNonEditable = function () {
        return this.each(function () {
            $(this).removeClass("ms-rte-layoutszone-inner-editable ms-rtestate-write").removeAttr("role aria-haspopup contentEditable aria-autocomplete aria-multiline");
        });
    };
    // add event actions before existing ones
    $.fn.preBind = function (type, data, fn) {
        this.each(function () {
            var $this = $(this);

            $this.bind(type, data, fn);

            var currentBindings = $._data(this, "events")[type];
            if ($.isArray(currentBindings)) {
                currentBindings.unshift(currentBindings.pop());
            }
        });
        return this;
    };
})(jQuery);
```

`preBind` function is used for transfer rich-text data to hidden field on before submit (usage below). Then use this:

```
// Rich Edit start
// mark div as Ribbon enabled rich edit area
$("#RTEDiv").SPEditable();

// transfer data from rich edit div to hidden field
$("input[id$='btnSubmit']").preBind("click", function () {
    var rText = $("#RTEDiv").html();
    $("input[id$='RTEDivHidden']").val(rText);
});
```

### Codebehind:

And the main part. In codebehind you have to do this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // tweak SPRibbon to show RichEdit
    SPRibbon current = SPRibbon.GetCurrent(this.Page);
    if (current != null)
    {
        current.MakeRTEContextualTabsAvailable(SPRibbon.RTEVisibilityContext);
        current.Visible = true;
        current.CommandUIVisible = true;
    }

    if (IsPostBack)
    {
        var body = RTEDivHidden.Value;
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(body))
        {
            // now you have pure HTML value of rich-text
        }
    }
}
```

To write something in rich-text div use this in JS:

```
$('#RTEDiv').html("<b>pure html text</b>");
```

And final result (sorry for lots of russian stuff):

[image]

Rich edit part of Ribbon correctly slides down and up, when you set of remove focus from rich-text div.

Hope this will help!

Comment: Thank you for sharing a complete solution! By the way, Could it  be possible to have this without a need for code-behind?

Comment: As I remember, main problem was to made Rich-text part of ribbon available and enabled. I'm not sure if this possible from inside JS. Hidden field and "prebind" method is optional, of course.

Comment: Thanks for the exhaustive answer. Really helped me to tame that damn WYSIWYG in a proper way.